# Prevent to rename to existing name

Tags: outliner

When i rename object (in outliner) to a 'name' that already exist, Blender will allow it and change the existing object to other name silently without me being notified. No warning or error etc. I don't like this behaviour. Can i change this default setting ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey :). It actually 'warns' you the first time, by adding .001 to the newer object's name. Only if you rewrite this appendix, it then renames the older object.

Comment: I don't get that. I have 2 cube , bigger cube named as BIG and small cube named as SMALL. If i select SMALL then rename it to BIG ( we assume that we don't know if BIG exist or not). The SMALL then become BIG without any warning while in the background and i don't realize it the BIG has been renamed to BIG.001 . I don't see any warning.

Comment: Maybe it's the kind of thing you should suggest here: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/

Comment: @andio You're right, I just noticed it only works with default object names. That's odd...

Comment: Yes i experienced bad situation where i rename them, i didn't knoe they exist and got no warning, later i realize the original object has been renamed. i'm confused this is dangerous for big project.